# Setting a cookie upon specific URL visit

Tags: php, functions, cookies

I'm trying to set up, when a specific page/url is visited that a cookie is set and saved.

So far I've tried this:

```
add_action('init', 'set_cookie', 1);

function set_cookie(){

  if ( $currentURL == 'https://25dni.si/delovanje-uma/' ) :

    if ( ! isset( $_COOKIE['opt_in'] ) ) :
        setcookie( 'opt_in', has_opt_in, time()+31556926);

    endif;

  endif;

}
```

Now, when I visit the specific URL, cookie is detected, but when I move on to another page, cookie is gone.

How can the cookie be saved?

I'm pretty new to this, please help me understand.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've used this and it works:

```
 add_action('init', 'optin_cookie', 1);

 function optin_cookie(){

   $currentURL = "https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

   if ( $currentURL == 'https://25dni.si/delovanje-uma/' ) :

    setcookie( 'opt_in', has_opt_in, time()+31556926, '/');

   elseif ( $currentURL != 'https://25dni.si/' ) :

     if ( ! isset( $_COOKIE['opt_in'] ) ) :

     endif;

    endif;

 }
```

I'm sure there is a much more elegant way to do it, but this got it working for me ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised it works at all since `$currentURL` is not defined in the function nor declared as a global.

Look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) for `setcookie()`. You did not declare a path for the cookie so try this:

`setcookie('opt_in','opt_in', time()+31556926, '/');`

That will set the cookie for the entire domain, if that's what you want to do.

Comment: Even if I do this, cookie isn't detected on the main page. It still shows only on the specific URL ... I checked the documentation, but still can't figure it out :/